# Executable Bundles in iOS Apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c

does anyone know if you can ship bundles (with executable code) in iOS apps? I know that downloading executable code is violating the iOS developer agreement, but if I shipped the bundles myself with the app, would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but you cannot link them at runtime. Dynamic linking is not available in iOS.

Comment: So for example `Class PluginClass = [bundle principalClass];` and working with that doesn't work?